# Help understanding exact mechanics of IV under heterogenous treatment effects (LATE)

Tags: mathematical-statistics, instrumental-variables

I have been reading [Blundell and Costa-Dias (2009)](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/%7Euctp39a/Blundell-CostaDias-27-09-2008.pdf) to try and understand the exact mechanics why standard IV breaks when heterogenous treatment effects are involved. On page 62 there is an almost helpful explanation:

[image: homogeneity screenshot]

The concept itself, that people with higher benefits from treatment may self-select into treatment and tarnish a traditional IV approach, makes complete sense. But there's several parts of this explanation which I don't mathematically understand. Specifically:

- The expectation $E[\alpha_i - \alpha^{ATE} | d=1,z]$ appears to arise out of nowhere. We started evaluating $E[e|z]$ (conditional on only $z$) but then suddenly we also became conditional on $d=1$ as well. I don't understand how this happens.
- I can't see how

  $E[e|z] = E[u_i|z] + E[d_i (\alpha_i - \alpha^{ATE})|z]$

  can become

  $E[u_i|z] + P(z_i) E[(\alpha_i - \alpha^{ATE})|d=1, z]$

  At first I thought that $E[d_i|z] = P(z)$, so this followed from the law that $E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]$ for independent random variables. But how can $d_i$ and $\alpha_i - \alpha^{ATE}$ be independent, if the claim here is that people with larger (smaller) treatment effects may self-select into (out of) treatment? Surely that implies $d_i$ and $\alpha_i - \alpha^{ATE}$ are correlated.